# Como setar um token no header?

Tags: node.js, express.js, jwt

Bom eu uso o jwt para gerar um token só que pelo exemplo que estava seguindo não mostrava exatamente como colcoar o token no header da aplicação. Alguém saberia como?
Obs.: Estou usando o express.

app.js //parte do arquivo principal

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
   next();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tens de criar uma palavra passe e inserir um middleware que faça a verificação e depois fazer o pedido http com esse token algures.

## No lado do servidor:

Há um exemplo bom [neste link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) com os passos principais são:

#### fazer require do `jwt` e configurar uma palavra passe

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // inserir o módulo jwt
    
app.set('superSecret', 'minha palavra passe'); // criar uma palavra passe de controlo
```

#### gerar um token

Dentro da função/path que tem a lógica de login, ou seja quando quiseres retornar um token a um utilizador que já esteja verificado podes fazer assim:

```
var token = jwt.sign('nome do utilizador ou objeto', app.get('superSecret'), {
  expiresInMinutes: 1440 // validade de 24 horas
});

// mostrar o token ao utilizador com um JSON
res.json({
  success: true,
  message: 'Enjoy your token!',
  token: token // este token é para guardar!
});
```

#### configurar um middleware para verificar o token

Por fim tens de defenir um middleware que corra em todas as path que precisas, ou seja nos url que devem estar protegidos. Essa parte é defenida na ultima linha deste código, primeiro tempos de defenir o router:

```
// ir buscar uma instância do router do Express.js
var apiRoutes = express.Router(); 

// middleware
apiRoutes.use(function(req, res, next) {

  // procurar a propriedade token em partes diferentes do pedido
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

  // descodificar caso haja um valor no request
  if (token) {

    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {      
      if (err) { // erro!
        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });    
      } else {
        // tudo ok! vamos passar esse valor para o req.decoded para ser usado no resto da aplicação
        req.decoded = decoded;    
        next();
      }
    });

  } else {

    // se não houver token no pedido/request, retornar erro
    return res.status(403).send({ 
        success: false, 
        message: 'No token provided.' 
    });
    
  }
});


// defenir quais os caminhos que devem estar protegidos
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

## No lado do cliente

Há várias opções:

#### via formulário/POST

neste caso é só fazer um input escondido com o token:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.dXNlcg.EvNc9eWXXeAjpMTMzV4xoW2EjtEcLeSwJwY5_8vE6X8" />
```

e o express vai ser encontrado com o `req.body.token`. (Não esquecer de juntar o middleware `body parser`)

### via url/query string

Neste caso é só juntar no url uma query string com `?token=xxxxx`, exemplo:

```
http://localhost:3000/api?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.dXNlcg.EvNc9eWXXeAjpMTMzV4xoW2EjtEcLeSwJwY5_8vE6X8
```

para ir buscar no Node pode usar-se `req.query.token`

### via request header/AJAX

Neste caso é só passar via request header do AJAX assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reqListener () {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
    oReq.open("GET", 'http://localhost:3000/api');
    oReq.setRequestHeader('x-access-token', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.dXNlcg.EvNc9eWXXeAjpMTMzV4xoW2EjtEcLeSwJwY5_8vE6X8');
    oReq.send();
</script>
```

e no Node ir buscar com `req.headers['x-access-token']`

---

## Exemplo:

Criei um exemplo com 3 ficheiros aqui: https://gist.github.com/SergioCrisostomo/445e4e37a6972c8493e8

Comment: Então, estou seguindo um exemplo parecido com esse, mas a minha dúvida é a respeito de como passar o valor do token para as páginas Ex:   req.body.token = passar por um campo na página  req.query.token = passar pela url,  req.headers['x-access-token'] = nesse caso aqui de passar no header, como eu faria para setar o token no header?

Comment: @Liw.S. testa isto: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18041849/2256325 posso juntar à reposta mais tarde quando chegar a casa.

Comment: Então, pelo que vi nessa pergunta eles passam o token por input hidden e é bem que a solução que achei, só queria passar pelo header para não ficar tão implicíto, mas obrigado por responder.

Comment: @Liw.S. juntei exemplos na resposta

Comment: Opa, acho que isso vai me servir. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Me ocorreu a dúvida, como eu faria um logout?

Answer (score 1):

Eu não uso o localStorage, o que faço é o seguinte:

1. No Javascript da página crio uma variável destinada ao token.
2. Envio a autenticação por ajax( tinha esquecido de falar isso antes, peço desculpas pelo mal entendido).
3. Quando autenticado, na API, crio um token, com a hora Unix (Todos os milissegundo desde 01/01/1970) de sua criação e usuario criptografados nele. No browser, passo o valor do token para a variável no javascript reservado a ele e removo o elemento pelo qual ele veio.
4. Ao enviar uma requisição, adiciono novamente o token.
5. Na API, decodifico o token e verifico sua validade.